# Why is while read data; do echo "$data" | cut -d: -f1; done so slow?

Tags: bash, performance, pipe

To get only the files that `git grep` prints, I can do

```
$ git grep "search" | cut -d':' -f1
```

So I made a short helper script `cutg` to which I can pipe to and I place at `~/bin/` dir.

```
#!/bin/sh
while read data; do
    echo "$data" | cut -d':' -f1
done
```

So now I can do

```
$ git grep "search" | cutg
```

But it is very slow.

Why so? How do I make it as fast as the 1st command?

Comment: Don't use a while read loop, just use cut directly on the STDIN of the function/script.

Comment: Calling any utility in a loop it notoriously slow.

Comment: You're running a new copy of `cut` every single time you get a new line of input. `cut` isn't built into bash -- it's an executable in `/usr/bin` or `/bin` or such; starting it up isn't free.

Comment: `while IFS=: read -r firstcol _; do printf '%s\n' "$firstcol"; done` is something to consider, if you really want a native-shell approach for some reason.

Comment: Or `while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%s\n' "${line%%:*}"; done`, likewise.

Comment: (to understand why `printf` instead of `echo`, see [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) -- particularly the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections).

Comment: (Also, this is a script, not a function. Scripts are run by a different shell instance and incur startup costs to invoke that shell, whereas shell functions are run in the shell you already have -- albeit in some scenarios, such as the pipeline one, in a `fork()`-ed off copy. To define a function for interactive use, you'd put the code in the `...` placeholder of `cutg() { ... }` in your `~/.bashrc` or such).

Comment: If you only want the file names, use the `--name-only` option with `git grep`. You don't need to parse the default output.

Comment: why not add `-l`? `git grep -l search` prints only the matching files.

Comment: Ah, I did not know about the `-l | --name-only` option. But I still find this post useful for myself as I have another alias `cuts` which does `cut -c3-` (not saving much on typing here) so I can do `git status -s | grep ^A | xargs scite` to filter out only added files and open in editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop reads each line of input, and **creates a new `cut` process for each line**.  The original one-liner used **a single `cut` process for all the input**.  Thankfully, you can inherit the script's standard input, and simply write

```
#!/bin/sh
exec cut -d: -f1 "$@" -
```

There's no need for your script to do anything at all, except replace itself with an appropriate `cut` invocation.  I included `"$@"` in case you want to provide additional arguments to `cut`, but you can safely leave that out if you're sure you don't need it.

Answer (score 3):

The script should be just:

```
cut -d':' -f1
```

or (better)

```
exec cut -d':' -f1
```

Shell loops are slow—especially if they invoke a process on each iteration, and especially if they're useless.